# Updates....constant why?

Tags: updates

Can we get a few more Updates?
Not a day goes by that I don't have spend Data downloading Updates.....
I'm not lucky enough to have an "unlimited" data IPS, mine is capped and this OS keeps eating up large chunks of it.
How about an option with a checkbox to NOT update something?

Answer (score 1):

AppCenter doesn’t start downloading updates until you launch it. If you can just cancel the update before it actually begins or if you don’t approve the update, you can just not download and install it and save data... though launching the AppCenter itself might take up a bit of data on it’s own...